# How to ignore blank and nonblank values in a for loop concurrently

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that timestamps "Column Y" when "Column X" is not blank. I'm trying to add a contingency that makes the script only timestamp "Column Y" if it's missing a timestamp. Currently the script will just overwrite the existing timestamps.

```
function markComplete() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var startingRow = 2;
  var maxRow = s.getLastRow();
  var data = s.getRange(startingRow, 1, maxRow, 29).getValues();
  var dateSent = new Date();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
   var row = data[i];
   var employee = row[23];
   var timestamp = row[29];


  if (employee != '') {
    s.getRange(i+2,29).setValue(dateSent);
    }
  }
  }
```

I've tried modifying the if statement to `if (employee != '' && timestamp == '')` but this just causes the script to do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

I tested this and it does not over write old timestamps.

```
function runOne() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn());
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for (var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i][23] && !vA[i][28]) {//columns x and y
      sh.getRange(i+2,29).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "E MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss"));//column y
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: My explanation was misleading. The actual columns are X (employee) and AC (timestamp). This still overwrites the existing timestamp when the function runs.

Comment: I'm looking to check whether the timestamp column already contains a timestamp whereas this solution references a separate additional column. sh.getRange(i+2,29) should be sh.getRange(i+2,28).

Comment: Column 29 is AC. vA[i][28] is column 29